# How can we reduce the time delay in IE ,while dowloading a html file?

Tags: php, html

i have a php site,

And in the site, there  is a section for downloading an html page ( which contains 5000 lines).

It is working in Mozilla, safari.

But it take a very huge time in IE, but it works.

How can i reduce the time delay fo IE browser

Comment: Do you mean downloading it as an attachement, or retrieving it to view in the browser?

Comment: @Alex JL - downloading it as an attachement, cause I wondering is IE taking longer time to render the huge HTML

Comment: You're using Apache, or another webserver?

Comment: @Alex JL -  and   ajreal 58  -actually downlaoding is working in IE, but while taking the page in  IE browser , it takes huge amount of time combaring to other browsers, also the jquery functions i the page also take huge time to work

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to to a newer Version...

Or try to break up the blocks. Make sure not the whole page is inside a single table/div, but its "broken open" (One section for the menue, one for main content ect...

This will allow IE to render parts of the page earlier. Also make sure the styles are available once you close the tag.

Answer (score 0):

you could gzip it - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php